# Electron como puedo personalizar el instalador de mi app

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron, vite, build

Tengo una app hecha con electron-vite y quiero saber como puedo personalizar el instalador que me genera.

Yo he ejecutar el comando build:win y todo bien pero el instalardor es muy simple y quiero saber como puedo hacer para agregarle mas cosas, como por ejemplo que haga algunas preguntas de preferencia del usuario o que realice alguna tarea mas en especifico cuando se este instalando.

No se si se pueda solo con electron o abra que usar algun recurso externo para hacer eso pero si alguien sabe de esto que me oriente porfa

Answer (score 0):

No se si ya pudiste encontrar una solucion, pero igualmente te dejo una.

si creaste el instalador con "nsis", de esta forma:

```
    "build": {
      "win": {
        "target": "nsis"
      }
    }
```

entonces tambien puedes configurar ciertas cosas en el instalador de la siguiente forma:

```
    "build": {
      "win": {
        "target": "nsis"
      },
      "nsis": {
        "uninstallDisplayName": "my-app-unistaller",
        "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true, //permite elegir el directorio de instalación
        "createDesktopShortcut": false, //crear icono en el escritorio
        "createStartMenuShortcut": false //crear icono en el menú de inicio
      }
    }
```

Estas son solo algunas opciones de personalizacion. Puedes ver mas en la documentacion de NSIS: https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis